# browser compatiblty and fonts

Tags: css, html

I am making an html page . Page is working good in firefox and google chrome but not working in ie 7 and 8 . IE 7 and 8 not getting the path of fonts and my html page isnt in center position. somebody please tell me how to sort it out

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'AntonioRegular';
src: url('font/antonio-regular.eot');
src: url('font/antonio-regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('font/antonio-regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('font/antonio-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('font/antonio-regular.svg#AntonioRegular') format('svg');

}
body
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

#wrapper
{
 width:1058px;
 height:1000px; 
 margin:0 auto;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a gate/sharp-character (`#`) to the first url.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'AntonioRegular';
   src: url('font/antonio-regular.eot');
   src: url('font/antonio-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('font/antonio-regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('font/antonio-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('font/antonio-regular.svg#AntonioRegular') format('svg');

}
```

See here: [How to Get IE8 to Support HTML5 Tags and Web Fonts](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-get-ie8-to-support-html5-tags-and-web-fonts/)

Or maybe the EOT file itself is broken.

Try removing the other src for other browsers and just let the first EOT file in. Is IE7/8 displaying the font?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct one.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AntonioRegular';
        src: url('font/antonio-regular.eot');
        src: url('font/antonio-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('font/antonio-regular.woff') format('woff'),
             url('font/antonio-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('font/antonio-regular.svg#AntonioRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```